# Kotlin for Android: setting a Google Maps marker image to a URL

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

I'd like to set a marker on a Google Map displayed by an Android Kotlin app to be a URL of my choice. It's clear that fetching the URL content needs to be done off the UI thread, and that coroutines are the approach here, so I'd like to run a few lines of code to fetch the URL and put it into a `BitmapDescription` object inside a coroutine, and then use that `BitmapDescription` to call `setIcon` on the `Marker` object to set the custom image.

I already have a `Marker`, and a URL. So I tried this:

```
    uiScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { // not sure this is the best way to launch in IO
        val furl = URL(myURL)
        val bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(furl.openConnection().getInputStream())
        val bd = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm)
        uiScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { // go back to UI thread; this crashes
            marker.setIcon(bd)
        }
    }
```

This is obviously not right because it crashes. The fetch of the URL and creating a `BitmapDescriptor` seems to be working fine as far as I can tell; once I have that `BitmapDescriptor`, how do I call `marker.setIcon` with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you said that fetching the image and creating `BitmapDescriptor` seems to be working fine, I can almost say that it is not right to do it yourself using an `URL` connection. The procedure of fetching and decoding images might involve many possible errors that could not be handled this way. It's better to delegate this responsibility as well as thread switching to a reliable tool such as [**`Glide`**](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/).

Let's write an extension function for the `Marker` using `Glide` in a `kotlin` file:

#### ExtensionFunctions.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker

fun Marker.loadIcon(context: Context, url: String?) {
    Glide.with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(url)
        .error(R.drawable.default_marker) // to show a default icon in case of any errors
        .listener(object : RequestListener<Bitmap> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(
                e: GlideException?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Bitmap>?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Bitmap?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Bitmap>?,
                dataSource: DataSource?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                return resource?.let {
                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(it)
                }?.let {
                    setIcon(it); true
                } ?: false
            }
        }).submit()
}
```

Now. it's just enough to call it over a marker object to load the image for it asynchronously:

```
marker.loadIcon(context, url)
```

Comment: Yeah, a whole bunch of suggestions boil down to "use Glide for this", and I'm leaning in that direction. I was loath to add another dependency to the app, but probably it's the simplest way; thank you for the pointers and the worked example!